# How to include Simplified Chinese - Mandarin and Cantonese resource locale in Android Studio

Tags: android, chinese-locale

I have a requirement to support **Simplified Chinese - Mandarin(Hans) and Cantonese(yue)** but while trying to add the above locale in Android studio , I'm not getting the exact region specifier. In android studio there are only 5 region codes are displayed, could you please anyone suggest how can i add the above two languages?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

CN: China -> Simplified Chinese / Mandarin

HK -> Traditional Chinese / Cantonese

TW -> Traditional Chinese / Mandarin